# How to extract Rust code with nested borrows / NLLs into a function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a large enum where I'm mutating data. The match cases are getting unwieldy, so I'd like to extract those into a separate function. However, it seems that it is not possible to do that due to lifetime issues.

### The example

Here is a [simplified example (Rust Playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=252299d5f57b8e74ec3b5cb2d6ae3554) of the issue at hand:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Variants {
    WithString(String),
    WithNum(usize),
}

fn manipulate(v: &mut Variants) {
    match v {
        Variants::WithString(s) => {
            if s.is_empty() {
                s.push_str("abc");
            } else {
                *v = Variants::WithNum(123);
            }
        }
        Variants::WithNum(n) => *v = Variants::WithString(n.to_string()),
    }
}
```

I have an enum that is not Clone or Default. Let's look at the `WithString()` case in detail:

- I have a `v: &mut Variants` variable.
- I have a `s: &mut String` variable that points into `v`. While the `s` borrow is active, I cannot use the outer object `v`.
- The Rust borrow checker is smart enough to recognize that if I stop using `s`, then I can access `v` again. I do this in the `else` branch.

I think that's an example of non-lexical lifetimes (NLLs)?

My actual usecase is worse in that the data structure is recursive, but I do not think that's relevant for an MCVE.

### Extracting the function doesn't work

When I try to extract the code in the `WithString(..)` case into a separate function, this will invariably fail, because function lifetimes do not seem to express that "can't use `v` while `s` is active" relationship:

```rust
match v {
    // rejected by borrow checker:
    // cannot borrow `*v` as mutable more than once at a time
    Variants::WithString(s) => manipulate_with_string(v, s),
    ...
}

// this function doesn't know that "s" points into "v"
fn manipulate_with_string(v: &mut Variants, s: &mut String) {
    if s.is_empty() {
        s.push_str("abc");
    } else {
        *v = Variants::WithNum(123);
    }
}
```

### Potential workarounds

Is there a way to solve this without drastically changing the data model?

I know of a couple solutions, but all are unsatisfactory:

- Just live with a very large `match` block.
- Pass the entire data structure into the extracted function and panic if it was the wrong variant – sounds like the most appropriate solution since this is easy to test. So roughly:

  ```rust
  fn manipulate_with_string(v: &mut Variants) {
    let Variants::WithString(s) = v else { unreachable!() };
    ...
  }
  ```
- Give up trying to solve this on a type system level, and check this dynamically via `RefCell` instead. However, that requires significant changes to the data model, and introduces the possibility of panics.
- Use owned data instead, i.e. using a signature `fn manipulate(v: Variants) -> Variants`. However, that requires re-architecting a lot of the data flow.
- Make the data `Default` so that I can `std::mem::take()` it at the beginning of the function and place it back just before I return. For example, this can be achieved by passing a `v: &mut Option<Variants>` instead. However, this gives up some type safety.
- Cook up some smart pointer or guard object using `unsafe` that can safely express this nested-borrow relationship. However, I am not confident that I can do this correctly.

So, is there a way to extract this `manipulate_with_string()` function, or am I stuck with one of the workarounds? Does Rust have any features/RFCs that might help with this in the future?

Comment: Your approach 2 (pass the whole thing and panic on wrong variant) is very a reasonable thing to do, and something I've seen in Rust codebases.

Comment: Are you worried about leaving `Variants` unmodified in case of panic, or not?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not worried about strong exception safety, which is why "take() the value then put it back before returning" is a potential workaround. There is no unsafe, no manual dropping. However, I'd prefer avoiding potentially-panicking stuff in the first place, which is one reason why I'm not excited about RefCell.

Comment: @amon: I added a third case to my answer, for when stealing is not possible, in case you find yourself in such a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Copy

First of all, I want to note that the problem is moot if the type is `Copy`. This may seem like a non-sequitur, but my personal experience is that many of my types end up being `Copy`.

In such a case, extracting is as simple as:

```rust
fn manipulate(v: &mut Variants) {
    *v = match v {
        Variants::WithString(s) => manipulate_with_string(*s),
        Variants::WithNum(n) => manipulate_with_num(*n),
    }
}

fn manipulate_with_string(mut s: String) -> Variants {
    if s.is_empty() {
        s.push_str("abc");
        Variants::WithString(s)
    } else {
        Variants::WithNum(123)
    }
}

fn manipulate_with_num(n: usize) -> Variants {
    Variants::WithString(n.to_string())
}
```

Do note that the *v* variable is NOT passed into the helper, only the *components* of each enum case are passed.

*Note: The above code may not compile depending on which `String` is used, the standard `String`, notably, not being `Copy`. One step at a time, please!*

#### Steal

Now, `Copy`, is not always possible... but the above structure is *still* usable regardless!

```rust
fn manipulate(v: &mut Variants) {
    *v = match v {
        Variants::WithString(s) => manipulate_with_string(mem::take(s)),
        //                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        Variants::WithNum(n) => manipulate_with_num(*n),
    }
}

fn manipulate_with_string(mut s: String) -> Variants {
    if s.is_empty() {
        s.push_str("abc");
        Variants::WithString(s)
    } else {
        Variants::WithNum(123)
    }
}

fn manipulate_with_num(n: usize) -> Variants {
    Variants::WithString(n.to_string())
}
```

That is, you don't need an `Option<Variants>` or a `Default` implementation for `Variants` to be able to steal the *components*, you just need the components themselves to have a cheap default state.

There is a concern that should the helper function panic, the variable `v` will be left into an "in-between" state; this may happen as the result of any mutation on a case component, though -- such as panicking after `push_str` has been called.

*Note: The standard collections' philosophy of cheap `Default` construction (no allocation) make them particularly suitable for such an endeavor.*

#### Branch In, Branch Out

Finally, the least desirable solution (in my opinion) is "duplicating" the control-flow:

- Encapsulate the (complex) branch and *conditional* transformation with the helper.
- Branch outside the helper on whether the transformation occurred, or not.

I do not particularly like it because I find it more difficult to understand what is going on, but should stealing not be an option...

```rust
fn manipulate(v: &mut Variants) {
    match v {
        Variants::WithString(s) =>
            if let Some(new) = manipulate_with_string(s) {
                *v = new;
            },
        Variants::WithNum(n) => *v = manipulate_with_num(*n),
    }
}

fn manipulate_with_string(s: &mut String) -> Option<Variants> {
    if s.is_empty() {
        s.push_str("abc");
        None
    } else {
        Some(Variants::WithNum(123))
    }
}

fn manipulate_with_num(n: usize) -> Variants {
    Variants::WithString(n.to_string())
}
```

Thankfully, the simple case is *still* simple (direct replacement), so only the more complex cases need adopt this less intuitive strategy.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because thinking more about stealing led me to a workable solution. I started with the "pass the entire enum and unwrap in each function" workaround, which then helped to identify some seams where I could use stealing to migrate parts to a value-oriented approach (`fn manipulate_with_strings(s: String) -> Variants`). Once that was done I could remove transitional steps like relying on `unreachable!()` or using stealing.

Answer (score 1):

The `manipulate_with_string` function can't exist, because at the signature level functions are being promised that the various `&mut` that are passed to them are non-aliased, something that is not true in the call to `manipulate_with_string(v, s)` (`s` aliases with the inside of `v`).

We could imagine some way to express that the second argument is some kind of projection of the first, but we don't have that tool in Rust yet.

Fundamentally what isn't supported is that this function has two modes of access to the data:

1. It might be mutating the value
2. It might be replacing the value altogether.

Rust is not good at abstracting over ownership.

One way of fixing this would be to have two functions,

```rust
fn manipulate(v: &mut Variants) {
    match v {
        Variants::WithString(s) => {
            if manipulate_with_string_can_mutate(&s) {
                manipulate_with_string_mutate(s)
            } else {
                manipulate_with_string_replace(v);
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way you keep the control flow that allows you to express when you want to replace the value and when you want to mutate it in place.

Of course in the minimal example it looks silly because each of the two functions would be one-liners but I'm assuming that in the real-world code, each of these would be longer.

Comment: Actually, it _is_ possible to have a single function `manipulate_with_string`. It's just not possible for it to take ownership of `v` _and_ borrow `s` at the same time, but just borrowing `s` works with no issue. See the _Branch In, Branch Out_ section in my answer.

Comment: I think this is a great answer because it explains some background for future reasons, but matthieum's ideas prompted further thoughts that allowed me to find a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `manipulate_with_string` a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! manipulate_with_string {
    ($v:expr, $s:expr) => {{
        let s = $s; // don't evaluate $s twice.
        if s.is_empty() {
            s.push_str("abc");
        } else {
            *$v = Variants::WithNum(123);
        }
    }};
}

fn manipulate(v: &mut Variants) {
    match v {
        Variants::WithString(s) => manipulate_with_string!(v, s),
        Variants::WithNum(n) => *v = Variants::WithString(n.to_string()),
    }
}
```

You'll have to be careful as to not accidentialy pass in expressions with a side effect (or avoid multiple evaluations as with `$s`) but otherwise the borrow checker only sees the code when the macro has been expanded, so it's happy but you still get to factor out the logic into a separate unit.

Comment: Personally, I dislike this approach, and prefer even keeping them all in a single giant function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This would solve the problem of having a giant `match` expression, but with the drawback that the extracted code isn't a function. I cannot reason about the extracted macro as a function. Tooling like Rustfmt and Rust-Analyzer doesn't work as well within macros. So I'd agree with Chayim that a single large match would typically be "better" (more maintainable).